# Cosmos DB - Should I set CosmosClientOptions.ApplicationRegion for my application?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have enabled multi-write enabled for the Cosmos account in azure portal. I don't understand if it is mandatory to set the ApplicationRegion using the SDK as well? If it is mandatory, what is the purpose of this property? I see the below documentation, but it is still not clear to me.

[Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzfH2.png)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose for ApplicationRegion is in scenarios where the SDK detects the region is no longer responsive, it will use that information to know which is the next closest region to failover to. If you do not set this value the SDK will failover to the next highest region listed in the portal or by failoverPriority in your Cosmos account configuration which may not be the closest.

Comment: More information regarding these semantics at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-sdk-availability

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Say, for example, I have multi-region writes enabled with 3 regions. West US, East US and East Asia (in this order in Azure portal). If I understand it right, if I dont specify the ApplicationRegion, the reads and writes will always be directed to West US (primary region because it's first in the list). Please correct me If I'm wrong.